# Design-time alternatives to a GUID?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

This isn't a complicated question.  I was just thinking through best practice and thought the community might be able to help.

**SOLUTION**

Have one file that contains an enumeration.  Source control can take care of collisions between multiple projects / developers.  If all assemblies are compiled and deployed at the same time, the ID will be unique (if cast to int).  Alternatively, we could assign a number to each enum.  The enum file will be added to each project via "Add As Link".

---

Original question

I'd like a unique id that begins at one, is set at design time, and is easy to implement in code to identify different classes.  In Visual Studio, we have a Tools / Create GUID. That's convenient, but at 16 bytes it's a little larger than I'd like.

It'd be nice to able to retrieve unique sequential integers from a web service.

Has someone already done this?  Does such a service already exist?

One alternative is to have a file that acts as a central register for developers... but I'd rather not if possible.  It would be nice to have two steps: 1. create class, 2. assign id.  Done.

---

Comment: message deserialization across n projects & n developers.  Doesn't look like the question will survive very long though given close(3)

Comment: I still don't get it. The fully qualified class name should be unique anyway

Comment: Matt: Not very unique, I guess.

Comment: @Matt: The hash code is not guaranteed to be unique or even the same over time.

Comment: Daniel, sometimes we cross assembly domain (no references), and classes can look be the same, but not be the same from a fully qualified name perspective.

Comment: @sgtz: That's what I am saying: The fully qualified class name will be unique and can be used as identifier. No need for strange magic numbers.

Comment: this.GetType().FullName.GetHashCode()? If uniqueness is the number one concern then GUID seems like the obvious choice - I don't see any compelling reason not to use it..

Comment: @sgtz - you're in very murky water here. This kind of nasty hack should **not** be necessary. I'd suggest your efforts are better spent trying to fix the design issues in your codebase..

Comment: @MattDavey as an example, would you consider RIA Services a nasty hack?  Sometimes you've got to think outside of either the CLR, or one implimentation of the CLR.  Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: @sgtz there is zero correlation between RIA services and the solution you have posted in your question. Perhaps I could have worded my warning in a slightly more friendly manner but I stand by it! Turn back now ;)

Comment: @MattDavey Matt Matt Matt... sigh.  Where to begin?  Probably this isn't the right place for an informal chat.  Pretty sure the compass heading is good though.   ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create this yourself if you want, make a web service and generate numbers.  If you generate the number at design time, alter your code at design time so that no other program cares what your magic number is.

GUIDs can be created relatively quickly on anyone's computer.  This means that you don't have to have some "central" database for numbers, which assists performance of certain applications.  Otherwise, use the GUID, which is a globally unique identifier that you can generate at run time and design time.